# Getting Python to print in Cyrillic in a feature extractor

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, nltk, python-unicode

I'm trying to train a program to learn to determine whether a newly given word in Russian is a noun or a verb.

```
def POS_features(word):
    return{'three_last_letters':word[-3:]}
print(POS_features(u'Богатир'))
```

Which returns {'three_last_letters': u'\u0442\u0438\u0440'}

Despite the

```
u'Богатир'
```

the last three letters print gobbledy-gook. How can I get Python to print in Cyrillic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns a `dict` and that's what was printed. Containers frequently print their `repr` - that is, a python-like representation of their contents. If you process the `dict` yourself, you get the right value.

```
>>> def POS_features(word):
...     return{'three_last_letters':word[-3:]}
... 
>>> val = POS_features(u'Богатир')
\>>> for k,v in val.items():
...     print k, v
... 
three_last_letters тир
```

I pasted your printed result back into my shell and got a `dict` again. Its not guaranteed that a string representation of a object can be built back into an object, but it works for simple types.

```
>>> val = {'three_last_letters': u'\u0442\u0438\u0440'}
>>> val
{'three_last_letters': u'\u0442\u0438\u0440'}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do something like that for informative features as well? classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)

Comment: I don't know what you use for a classifier so can't say for sure, but generally, yes. Once you get the str or unicode objects, you can just print them. Print will use `sys.stdout.encoding` which may not support your characters, which is a different problem. For instane, if you are on windows and don't have a cyrillic code page, it may end in tears.

Comment: As an aside, python 3 has been out a long time and has more robust unicode support. If you aren't forced to use python 2, switch.

Comment: Not just "more robust" support, but Python's 2 text model is simply not worth wrapping your head around. If you're just working with Russian, switch to Python 3 today.

Comment: Specifically, switch to Python 3.6.  It has much better support for printing Unicode on the Windows console, and would print your Cyrillic characters even if the console code page default doesn't support them.